# Why are these phrases “vulgarly considered appurtenance of poetry”?

Tags: meaning

> There were mistakes  in grammer, in spelling of course,and worse―there
>   were such phrases as "'**thwart the rolling foam**","**waiting for my
>   true love on the lea**,"etc,, which are vulgarly considered
>   appurtenance of poetry;

This is from introduction of the poetry by Francis Ledwidge in 1914. I do not understand why these two sentences are vulgarly considered appurtenance of poetry;

I am glad if some one would kindly give me some advice.

Comment: The underlying idea is that "common folk" think such phrases are poetic.  *thwart* would probably be spelled *'thwart* as a contracted form of *athwart*, a  preposition which was becoming an archaism. It means "against" or "counter to".  The point the author was making is that to those of uneducated tastes,  a poem has to sound a little old-fashioned and must use old words and musty themes; it could not be fashioned from contemporary vernacular and speak about contemporary life.

Comment: *grammEr* cannot be an introduction in any poetry!

Answer (score 2):

"Vulgarly" here means "by the common people" (it doesn't mean "rudely"). An appurtenance is something extra that is added.

The example phrases use a high romantic style, that was popular in the 19th century, but was going out of style in the 20th century. A romantic style has been added to the sentences.

It seems that the author is criticising the "common folk" for thinking that poems must have a romantic style. He is criticising people who think that a poem must use old-fashioned language, and only deal with themes like nature or love. This is part of a movement called "modernism", which affected all the arts.

Ironically, seen from the 21st century, his modernism also seems rather old-fashioned.

Comment: +1. The criticism is actually Lord Dunsany's, in the intro.

Answer (score 1):

> There were mistakes in grammar, in spelling of course,and worse―there
>   were such phrases as "'thwart the rolling foam","waiting for my true
>   love on the lea,"etc,, which are vulgarly considered appurtenance of
>   poetry;

appurtenance here means belonging to. It comes from the French, appartenir, to belong to.

It is still used in real estate legal contracts: the property and its appurtenances i.e. the property and what goes along with it (typically outbuildings or sheds etc.)

According to the author, phrases like that were thought, by the "common people", to come from the domain of poetry. That meaning of vulgar is not much used today. Meaning 5 in Merriam Webster.

a : of or relating to the common people : plebeian
b : generally current : public the vulgar opinion of that time
c : of the usual, typical, or ordinary kind

[appurtenance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appurtenance?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld)
[vulgar](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vulgarly)